# Transpiler Error: Number of qubits greater than maximum in coupling map

Tags: qiskit, programming

Transpiler Error: *Number of qubits (2) in circuit11 is greater than maximum (1) in the couplings map*

```
# Initialize two qubits and create Entanglement using Hadamard and CX/CNOT Gate
q = qiskit.QuantumRegister(2)
c = qiskit.ClassicalRegister(2)
qc = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(q, c)
qc.h(q[0])
qc.cx(q[0], q[1])
qc.measure(q, c)
job_exp = qiskit.execute(qc, backend=backend, shots=1024, max_credits=3)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TranspilerError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7b13276b10ae> in <module>()
      9 qc.cx(q[0], q[1])
     10 qc.measure(q, c)
---> 11 job_exp = qiskit.execute(qc, backend=backend, shots=1024, max_credits=3)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/qiskit/execute.py in execute(experiments, backend, basis_gates, coupling_map, backend_properties, initial_layout, seed_transpiler, optimization_level, pass_manager, qobj_id, qobj_header, shots, memory, max_credits, seed_simulator, default_qubit_los, default_meas_los, schedule_los, meas_level, meas_return, memory_slots, memory_slot_size, rep_time, parameter_binds, schedule_circuit, inst_map, meas_map, scheduling_method, **run_config)
    249                                 seed_transpiler=seed_transpiler,
    250                                 optimization_level=optimization_level,
--> 251                                 backend=backend)
    252 
    253     if schedule_circuit:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/qiskit/compiler/transpile.py in transpile(circuits, backend, basis_gates, coupling_map, backend_properties, initial_layout, layout_method, routing_method, seed_transpiler, optimization_level, pass_manager, callback, output_name)
    205                                            callback, output_name)
    206 
--> 207     _check_circuits_coupling_map(circuits, transpile_args, backend)
    208 
    209     # Transpile circuits in parallel

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/qiskit/compiler/transpile.py in _check_circuits_coupling_map(circuits, transpile_args, backend)
    245                                   'in {} '.format(circuit.name) +
    246                                   'is greater than maximum ({}) '.format(max_qubits) +
--> 247                                   'in the coupling_map')
    248 
    249 

TranspilerError: 'Number of qubits (2) in circuit11 is greater than maximum (1) in the coupling_map'
```

Comment: What's the `backend` you are using?

Comment: It seems that you use a backend with lower number of qubits than actually used in your circuit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that you are trying to execute a circuit on a backend that has fewer qubits than used in your circuit. In this case you are trying to execute a 2 qubit circuit on a device that only has one qubit. To fix this I would use a different backend which has 2 or more qubits. You can see how many qubits a backend has by looking at it on the IBM Quantum website or by calling `backend.configuration()`